# Install SQL Server 2008 Express with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008-r2

I am doing a custom install of Visual Studio 2010 onto a new development box.

The target machine already has SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 installed.

I see one of the components is **SQL Server 2008 Express Service** however this machine already has SQL Server installed on it.  Its a 1.6 GB disk space savings plus I dont like to add unnecessary services (or installs) if I do not have to.

So my question is, would I want to still install the "express service" even though I have the full Developer Version of SQL Server 2008 R2 already installed?  And if so, why?   Is there a future benefit or is this somewhat redundant and can I save space and keep this box better tuned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wanted to update this as I eventually learned that I did not need to install the express service of SQL Server 2008 because I already had the full developer version installed.  There have been no ill effects and I was able to save the disc space required for the express service plus the RAM needed to run and maintain that instance.